# App Crash while using GMSPlace Picker in ios 9

Tags: ios, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsplace

GMSPlacePicker is getting crash when user does not select any place from picker view and press Back button.

**ERROR :**

> -[UIWindow _shouldAnimatePropertyWithKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance

**Code:**

```
- (void)findNearByPlace :(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center {


CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001,
                                                              center.longitude + 0.001);
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001,
                                                              center.longitude - 0.001);
GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                     coordinate:southWest];
GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
_placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

[_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    if (place != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Place name:%@",place.formattedAddress);
        placeName = place.name;
        placeAddress = place.formattedAddress;
        //hide previous marker
        self.mapMarker.map = nil;
        self.locaitonTitle = place.name;
        self.locationAddress = place.formattedAddress;
        self.mapMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:place.coordinate];
        self.mapMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_ellipse_black.png"];
        mapLattitude = place.coordinate.latitude;
        mapLongitude = place.coordinate.longitude;
        self.mapMarker.draggable = YES;
        markerTag = @"2";
        markerDefault = @"default";
        self.mapMarker.userData = @{};
        self.mapMarker.map = self.mapView_;
        [self showLocationPopUp:placeName address:placeAddress withCoord:place.coordinate];
        //[self showLocationFoundView];
    } else {

        [self addOwnLocation : longPressCoord];
        NSLog(@"No Place is selected yet");
    }
}];
```

}

Any Solution?

Comment: Its not about your code its something with GMSPlacePicker library in the iOS 9.
You can debug enabling  Zombie objects to see what is deallocated .

Comment: I have enabled zoombie objects. but no success.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Our solution is to disable the `Back` navigation button by hiding the navigation bar.

Objective-C:

```
[placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace * __nullable result, NSError * __nullable error) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}];

//Hide the navigation bar
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UINavigationController *rootViewController = (UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
    rootViewController.navigationBarHidden = true;
});
```

Swift:

```
placePicker.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //DO SOMETHING     
})

//Hide the navigation bar
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
     let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
     (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).navigationBarHidden = true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but i need that back button functionality in my app.

Comment: @RituGarodia, it was just a workaround. I don't know if it's already fixed though.

Comment: This Crash has been fixed in Google Maps 1.10.4 sdk.